# How i can trigger build from jenkinsfile using cron syntax?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

im using multibranch jenkins style each branch has its own jenkinsfile, i have added triggers in jenkinsfile but it didnt trigger anything on the specified time (8pm), im not sure if im missing something

```
 agent {
    node {
      label 'master'
    }
  }

  triggers {
           cron(env.APP_NAME == 'DICTIONARY' ? '00 20 * * *' : '')
  }

  stages {
    stage('SCM Checkout') {
      steps {
        git(branch: 'test', url: 'https://gitlab.testral.ba/amramework.git', poll: true, credentialsId: 'GitlabCred')
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the change in `cron` to catch, you need to run your Jenkinsfile once manually *in the correct branch*. After that, check in "View Configuration" that your cron succeeded ("Build periodically" should be checked and contain the schedule).

If it has not, it could be that, at the time when triggers are evaluated, your `env.APP_NAME` differs from  `'DICTIONARY'`.

To debug the `env`, you may add the following:

```
println "env.APP_NAME is ${env.APP_NAME}" // will run before pipeline

pipeline { 
 agent {
    node {
```

As a side-note, it's recommended using `H` instead of minutes, so not all hourly builds fall exactly on the hour:

```
triggers {
           cron(env.APP_NAME == 'DICTIONARY' ? 'H 20 * * *' : '')
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I'd have below referred jenkinsfile structure. How to add trigger in this case?: ...plan = { stage('Build tests') { sh "docker build --network=host --build-arg CACHE_BUST=\$(date +%s) -t ${DOCKER_IMAGE} ." } stage('Run tests') {.....